# How to avoid java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB , save image to Firebase Storage and its download uri to Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, out-of-memory, stack-overflow, firebase-storage

I am trying to get a photo from user either by taking new one with `camera` or from `gallery`. It works perfectly, I can get photo and display it on the screen. what I want to do is, to save the image into `Firebase` Storage and the link in `Firebase Database` as well.

```
public void selectImage()
{
    final String[] items = {"Camera", "Gallery","Cancel"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Pick a photo");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if(which == 0)
            {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From your Camera");
                mUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
            }
            else if(which == 1)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Foto seçin"), SELECT_FILE);
            }
            else if(which == 2)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            try {
                Bitmap thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                        getContentResolver(), mUri);
                ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(getRealPathFromURI(mUri));
                int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
                Bitmap rotatedBitmap;
                switch (orientation) {
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                        rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(thumbnail, 90);
                        break;

                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                        rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(thumbnail, 180);
                        break;

                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                        rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(thumbnail, 270);
                        break;

                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                    default:
                        rotatedBitmap = thumbnail;
                }
                profilePicture.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
            mUri = data.getData();
            profilePicture.setImageURI(mUri);
            setPhoto(mUri);
        }
    }
    final StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profile_photos/" + mUser.getNumber() + ".jpg");
    reference.putFile(mUri);
    reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            DatabaseReference reference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mUser.getNumber()).child("Picture");
            reference1.setValue(uri);
        }
    });
}
```

I get **java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB** error when I want to save image to `Firebase`. Even though, the image is saved in Storage, no change appears in `Database`. How can I avoid this error and save download `uri` of the image in the `Database`?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue. It turned out that your cannot `setValue` of an URI.

Try to convert your URI to a String than the fatal error will disappear.

```
 reference1.setValue(uri.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing is wrong, you will have to upload the image to **`StorageReference`** and not directly to the database, i**n the database you will store the reference path returned after the upload.**

Comment: Could you please explain where my mistake is? I first out photo into Storage, then try to get downloadUrl.

Comment: @JavidHaji-zada your code looks ok, I am sorry I overlooked before can you post your error log, let's start from that

Comment: @JavidHaji-zada have you set up the storage component in the firebase console

Comment: Yes, I have set it up already. The problem is now related to uploading to storage. It works somehow, what I need is to get downloadUrl() as soon as the photo is uploaded to storage, and save that url into database

Comment: No, I no longer save it to database. Alternatively, I retrieve image directly from Storage.